# Use of Fresnel lenses

Tags: optics, lenses

Major camera manufacturers are now using Fresnel lens elements in high end telephoto lenses to reduce weight. I can understand the use of such lenses in light concentration applications but how can they perform to the high standard of photographic imaging? I would think that the facets would produce stray light, thus reducing image contrast, among other possible consequences.

Comment: I believe you're correct. The use of a Fresnel lens will result in loss of light, but the reduction in weight is sometimes worthwhile. For instance compare these two similar lenses: one has a 1-stop loss and a Fresnel lens, but it is much lighter (and cheaper) than the other. https://www.adorama.com/nk50056e.html https://www.adorama.com/nk5004fl.html

Answer (score 0):

@diffycue linked to [an advertisement for a Nikon lens](https://www.adorama.com/nk50056e.html) that uses "phase Fresnel lens elements."

Here's what [Nikon's own web site](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/af-s-nikkor-500mm-f%252f5.6e-pf-ed-vr.html) has to say:

> when there is a strong light source within the frame or when light enters the lens from outside of the frame, ring-shaped colored flare may occur according to shooting conditions. This phenomenon can be minimized with “PF Flare Control” to be included inCapture NX-D (ver.1.1.0 or later).

In other words, the facets *do* produce stray light, and the stray light does reduce the image contrast and, it does have other consequences; but all of those consequences are predictable, and digital image processing software is able to (mostly?) undo them.

I *suppose* that the DSP is performed in the camera if the camera exports a .jpeg file (or other "common" image format), and it most likely is performed by software running on a workstation that imports "RAW" images from the camera.

---

P.S., This actually is a new twist on an idea that's been out there for a few years: My own camera, a Fujifilm X-T30, uses lenses that are not corrected for certain geometric distortions. The in-camera software knows about the distortion and corrects for it when saving .jpeg files, and software on my workstation does the same if I import the RAW files.